# como hacer que 2 divs ocupen el 100% de su contenedor cuando cambien su tamaño si hay un min-width en uno de ellos?

Tags: css

tengo una duda algo tonta pero aun soy algo nuevo a css.
Tengo un contenedor que tiene ancho de 100vw, tengo 2 div juntos en una fila, el primero tiene ancho 25% y el segundo 75%; el primero tiene ademas un min-width:max-content asi no se achica mas que su contenido. Cuando reduzco el tamaño de la ventana, se reducen ambos div proporcionalmente a su porcentaje, pero cuando llega al tope de reduccion (min-width) el primer div deja de achicarse y el segundo lo hace con su misma proporcion, haciendo que el contenido total se desborde de la pantalla (el ancho del contenedor es 100vw). Intente poner el 75% como max-width pero sigue desbordando, hay alguna manera de hacer que no desborde con una propiedad de css o bootstrap? (no quiero usar js)

Comment: Agrega tu código editando la pregunta, asi podemos probarlo